# Is it possible to run query profiler for mdf files under App_Folder?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, profiling

I am using a small demo project from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170921/MvcContrib-Grid-Paging-and-Searching-in-ASP-NET-MV. It has an App_Data folder with the database, I wanted to do run the profiler against its database to compare with my own project. In my project there is no App_data folder, my database is on the actual sqlexpress and I am using Anjlab as profiler, I can see the queries going to my own database without any problem but I dont see anything going to database for the App_data folder.

I am wondering if there is a way to use the profiler for mdf files under the App_data folder.

Thanks.